# if $y\in \mathbb{R}$ does $x^3-y=0$ has always a real solution?

Tags: real-analysis

As written on the title, I want to see, can we always say that $x=y^{\frac 13}$ is always  real ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, although there are two complex solutions as well.

Comment: Just a note that notation $y^{1/3}$ only works for positive $y$, while there is a real solutions to $x^3-y=0$ for any $y$.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you lack to prove that such a real solution $x$ will always exist.  Did you consider cases by trichotomy ($y \gt 0$, $y=0$, $y\lt 0$)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A visual indication comes from graphing $y=x^3$ and seeing that any horizontal line hits the graph at one point.  A real proof will depend on the tools you have available.  The mean value theorem will get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let $f(x) = x^3-y$.  Choosing appropriate $x$ values will show that $\exists x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1) > 0 > f(x_2)$, and by the Intermediate Value Theorem $f$ has a zero.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $y$, the equation
$$x^3 - y = 0$$
has $3$ solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra. Since zeros of polynomials come in complex conjugate pairs, there must be a zero that is its own complex conjugate. This solution is real and is a cube root of $y$.

(Note that this argument works for any odd power - i.e there is always a real $(2n+1)th$ root of any real number.)

Comment: Using fundamental theorem of algebra might be troublesome since you either have to prove it using complex analysis or Galois theory and it might become circular on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because of the *intermediate value theorem*: any $y\in\mathbf R $ is between the cubes of two  consecutive integers, say $n^3\le y<(n+1)^3$.

If $y=n3$, the problem is solved . If  $n^3< y<(n+1)^3$, we can apply the I.V.T. to the continuous function $x^3$: there exists a real number $x$, $n<x<n+1$, such that $x^3=y$.